# Git always wants a password instead of using the ssh key at pulling from GitLab using git SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, public-key

Once it was working for a short time, but now git always asks for the password instead of using the key when `push` or `pull` to the GitLab server. According the server admin in the log of the GitLab server there is only the keyboard authentification request, no public key request at all. When I issue a `ssh -v` to the GitLab server all works fine.
The problem occurs in the windows command line and in the git bash too. Also when TortoiseGit uses the git ssh this happens. When TortoiseGit uses the windows SSH it seems to work.
What could happen that git SSH doesn't use the public key anymore?

Comment: `GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch` to see what Git is doing. `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git fetch` to see what SSH is doing.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the key files are seached at the U: drive, instead in the Windows or Git directories at the C: drive. How to change the search path back to the C: drive?

Comment: Seems to use the HOMEDRIVE variable, whereby the drive availability is dependent of login type. I try to solve this internal.